# Python Sockets Cant Find Each Other on the Same Network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi

I have seen so many of these questions being asked before but none of the solutions seem to apply to my case. I set up a server and a client socket script to communicate with each other. Whenever I run them on the same machine, they work and the server prints "Connection received" but when I run them on different machines, they don't. The IP is the IP of the server, I have disabled my windows firewalls/antivirus and I am certain they are both on the same network. When attempting to connect, it stalls for about 20 seconds then gives error 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Some info that may be useful:

Server: Raspberry Pi 3b, Python 3.4.2

Client: Windows 10 PC, Python 3.7.8

Note: These scripts used to work in the past. I don't use them frequently so I don't know exactly when they stopped working, but I assume it was around the time we switched our internet package as this also broke some of our wireless smart home devices.

Does anyone know why they can't find/connect to each other? Thanks.

Server Code

```py
import socket
from time import sleep

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.0.34', 1234))
s.listen(5)

clientsocket = None

print("Listening")

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print("Connection Received")
    break

#The code that runs after a client successfully connects
```

Client Code

```py
import socket
from time import sleep

print("Looking")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.34', 1234))
print("Connected")
sleep(20) #This is just so I can read any errors before the window closes for testing.

#code to start sending data
```

Comment: Don't bind the server to `192.168.0.34`. Bind it to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this didn't work. However, I did notice from some testing that if I use the hostname of the pi ("MyPi") instead of the IP in the client script, it does the same thing but if I spell the name wrong by just one letter instead, I get a different error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed. This leads me to think that the address is correct and I am just receiving it wrong. I am not sure what is wrong with it so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code - I just connected from a Windows 11 client to Raspberry Pi Zero running your code no problem. Sounds like there's a firewall somewhere stopping the comms. When you switched the internet did you get a new router? Could that be running a firewall? Do you use ssh between the Windows PC and the raspberry pi? Does that work OK? Try changing the port to '80' (i.e. http port) - you'll need to run as sudo - if that works then it's probably a firewall somewhere limiting the ports you can connect to.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try that out. Yes, I did get a new router. I’ll take a look at the firewall settings. Yesterday I believe I was able to ssh into the pi without being stopped.